# Rails: searching with pseudo-relevancy

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search

I'm trying to write a search method that searches the full text of an `Article` and sorts the results by the number of occurrences of the search term in that full text. Something like this:

```
def search
  term = params[:term]
  @articles = Article.where("body like ?", "%#{term}%")
  @articles.each do |a|
    b = a.body.count(term)
  end
  @articles = @articles.order("#{b} desc").limit(10).pluck(:name)
  render json: @articles, b
end
```

The above obviously doesn't work, it's just there to explain the concept. Any ideas would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using a full-text search library to achieve this.

If you're using Postgres as your database, you can use [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) which adds scopes to your models which make use of Postgres' build in full-text search functionality.

Alternatively if you don't want to add any external dependencies you can use [Acts as Indexed](https://github.com/dougal/acts_as_indexed) to add ranked full-text results to your app.

A fairly comprehensive list of the various options can be found at [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_search).

Disclosure: I'm the author of acts_as_indexed.

Comment: And if I just wanted to return a property of the results (and like a relevancy score or similar) is that possible?

Comment: At the moment it is not possible to get the relevancy score for a record. This is a much asked-for feature, and one I plan to get to at some-point this year.